# Setting a component state outside of the component results in error

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

Building a modal component that opens up a bootstrap modal from any part of the app then sets custom states for that component outside of it. It works fine but i always just get this error once i open the modal and I cant seem to figure out why:

> Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.` Doesnt really break anything but error keeps showing up.

My code:

layout.js

```
import React from "react";
import {Link} from 'react-router';
import NotificationSystem from 'react-notification-system';

import AppHeader from "#/ui/header/AppHeader";
import AppFooter from "#/ui/footer/AppFooter";

import Modal from "#/ui/modals/modal/Modal";

import "@/main.scss";
import './layout.scss';


export default class Layout extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        app.notify.clear = this.refs.notificationSystem.clearNotifications;
        app.notify = this.refs.notificationSystem.addNotification;
        app.modal = this.refs.modal.updateProps;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div class="app">
                <div class="header">
                    <AppHeader page={this.props.location.pathname.replace('/', '')}/>
                </div>
                <div class="body">
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
                <div class="footer">
                    <AppFooter />
                </div>

                <NotificationSystem ref="notificationSystem" style={false} />
                <Modal ref="modal" />
            </div>

        );
    };
}
```

Modal.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import SVGInline from "react-svg-inline";
import {closeSvg} from '#/utils/Svg';

export default class Modal extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            showHeader: true,
            showFooter: false,
            title: "",
            size: '',
            className: '',
            id: '',
            footerContent: null,
            showSubmitBtn: true,
            showCancelBtn: true,
            cancelBtnText: "Cancel",
            successBtnText: "Save Changes",
            onModalClose: () => {},
            showModal: false,
            html: () => {}
        }

        this.updateProps = this.updateProps.bind(this);
        this.hideModal = this.hideModal.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        var self = this;

        var $modal = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this));
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if(this.state.showModal) {
            $('body').addClass('modal-open');
        } else {
            $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
        }
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        // $('body').removeClass("modal-open");
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        console.log(nextProps);
    }

    updateProps(args) {
        let merged = {...this.state, ...args};
        this.setState(merged);
    }

    hideModal() {
        this.setState({
            showModal: false
        });

        this.state.onModalClose();
    }

    buildFooter() {
        if(this.props.footerContent) {
            return (
                <div class="content">
                    {this.props.footerContent}
                </div>
            )
        } else if(this.props.showCancelBtn && this.props.showSubmitBtn) {
            return (
                <div class="buttons">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onClick={this.props.onModalClose}>{this.props.cancelBtnText}</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">{this.props.successBtnText}</button>
                </div>
            );
        } else if(this.props.showCancelBtn) {
            return (<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onClick={this.props.onModalClose}>Close</button>);
        } else if(this.props.showSubmitBtn) {
            return (<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Save changes</button>);
        }
    }

    render() {
        let {
            id,
            className,
            onModalClose,
            size,
            showHeader,
            title,
            children,
            showFooter,
            showModal,
            html
        } = this.state;

        return (
            <div class={`modal-wrapper`} >
                {
                    showModal ?
                        <div class={`modal fade in ${className}`} role="dialog">
                            <div class="bg" ></div>
                            <div class={`modal-dialog ${size}`}>
                                <div class="modal-content">

                                    { showHeader ?
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                                                <SVGInline svg={closeSvg} />
                                            </button>
                                            <h4 class="modal-title">{ title }</h4>
                                        </div> : '' }


                                    <div class="modal-body" >
                                        {html()}
                                    </div>

                                    {  showFooter ?
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            { this.buildFooter() }
                                        </div> : ''
                                    }

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    : ''
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

SelectDefaultImage.js

```
import React from "react";
import sass from "./selectdefaultimage.scss";
import FullScreenImageModal from "#/ui/modals/fullscreenimagemodal/FullScreenImageModal";

export default class SelectDefaultImage extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            showModal: false,
            imgUrl: false,
        }
    }

    showImageModal(image) {
        this.setState({
            showModal: true,
            imgUrl: image
        });
    }

    hideImageModal() {
        this.setState({
            showModal: false,
            imgUrl: false
        })
    }

    onSelectImageClick(e, image) {
        $('.select-image-widget .active').removeClass('active');
        $(e.target).parent().addClass('active');

        // this.props.selectedImage(image)
    }

    render() {
        let {listingManager, images, selectedImage} = this.props;
        let {imgUrl} = this.state;

        return (
            <div class="content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <label class="control-label" for="description">Select an Image</label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="select-image-widget">
                            {
                                images.map((image, idx) => {
                                    return (
                                        <div class="selecter" key={idx}>
                                            <div class="img" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${listingManager.LISTINGS_PATH + image})` }} onClick={(e) => { this.onSelectImageClick(e, image) }}></div>
                                            <i class="fa fa-search-plus" aria-hidden="true" onClick={()=> {this.showImageModal(image)}}></i>
                                        </div>
                                    )
                                })
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {
                    this.state.showModal ?
                        app.modal({
                            showModal: true,
                            className: "fullscreen-image-modal",
                            size: "modal-lg",
                            html: () => {
                                return (<img src={listingManager.LISTINGS_PATH + imgUrl} />);
                            }
                        })
                    : ''
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: The code in the question doesn't seem to be having any issues that could be causing the said error. Have you included everything?
On the other hand, since you are importing external libraries, this error could be coming from one of those.

Comment: And although not related to the question directly, try to avoid the use of jquery with react. If you think you need jquery, that means you are not doing react the right way. 
https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html

Comment: @PubuduDodangoda the error is in the Modal.js only when showModal is set to true. Only happens once the modal shows up. Ive included all the code associated with this issue. I am stuck myself and ive been at it for like 4 hours now...

Comment: What is the purpose of troolr?

Comment: Sorry about that, meant to change that too app.modal, just updated my question

Comment: What is `app.modal`? I can't see where `app` is defined?

Comment: app is just a global {} variable which can be accessed through any file. app.modal is the <Modal /> component which is shown above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the error is most likely that in `SelectDefaultImage`, you call `app.modal` from within the render method, and `app.modal` is `this.refs.modal.updateProps`, which does a `setState`. If you put the `app.modal` call in `showImageModal`, I expect the error to go away. However, setting the state of a another component by means of refs and globals is a bit of a React antipattern, so I would recommend to do some refactoring and use props to pass the data.

Comment: I second this. Also, you have functions in the state. Not recommended either.